# Changing font color in tcl programming

Tags: windows, tcl

I am new to Tcl language.  I have a script I am trying to change the font color.  What I have so far isn't working

```
puts "\033\[1;31m";
puts "Color Should change."
puts "\033\[0m";
```

What I am getting is an ascii arrow[;31m i was expecting to see the font color change when i ran my script.

Comment: What's the context here?  What operating system, what kind of terminal or other environment is this output going to?

Comment: The OS is windows 10, and it's running from dos.  `tclsh script.tcl`  Tcl version `8.5`

Comment: By "dos" I imagine you mean `cmd` ?

Comment: This may be relevant: https://superuser.com/questions/413073/windows-console-with-ansi-colors-handling

Comment: yes cmd, i am old so i still refer to it as dos.  I will follow the link and see it if can figure it out.  thank you for the link and the help.

Comment: Tcl 8.7 onwards will call `SetConsoleMode()` (in code that I originally wrote) but not with the flag mentioned on the superuser page; I don't know what impact that will have (it just toggles other parts of the mode bits). Tcl 8.6 and before don't call it at all. *All* handling of that sort of thing on Windows will be in the file `win/tclWinConsole.c` in the source distribution. 8.7 is not finalized yet; if we *should* support this then now is a very good time to ask for it.